# Azure function response status code is always 200

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I have a function which is supposed to return error status 500/400 based on some internal logic. For some reason, Azure function keeps returning HTTP status 200 irrespective of what I return.

Here is a sample

```
    if (err) { 
        console.error('some error :', err);                           
        context.res = { status: 400, body: err };
    } else {
        context.res = processRequest(context, req);
    }

    context.done();
```

It returns status 200 OK

[image]

Below is my function bindings

```
{
  "bindings": [
{
  "authLevel": "function",
  "type": "httpTrigger",
  "direction": "in",
  "name": "req"
},
{
  "type": "http",
  "direction": "out",
  "name": "res"
}  
],  "disabled": false
}
```

Comment: actually, looking at the docs, this should work, unless i misinterpret something. can you show your output binding? are you using functions 2.0? what is your node version?

Comment: Thank you @4c74356b41 had to dig that docs links for that

Comment: can you give me the link where you found that? i cant seem to find it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah! finally had to set IsRaw property to true

[image]

[MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node)

```
            context.res = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            status: 400,
            body: {
                err
            },
            isRaw: true,
            };
```